# how to open a url from PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server

I have a `url` that executes lots of `javascript` code. I want to open this from `PowerShell` to schedule.

But as it executes `javascript` code, `PowerShell` not opening this `url` properly.

What I tried?

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "myurl"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "myurl"
```

both gives me error.

> Invoke-RestMethod :    My Apps
>   -->
>       window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
>       function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
>       gtag('js', new Date());
>
> ```
> gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-2');
>
>
>     At line:1 char:1
> ```
>
> + Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://spos.rkapps.in/SendLCNotifyMails"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Note: `Start-Process "myurl"` runs as expected, as it opens a real browser but I want to schedule this when my server is on logoff mode so it does not runs.

How to open it?

Comment: Please show us _the full error message_ (except the URI, if present)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, question is updated with full error code

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be easier done for you:

here is a script that just open a browser which goes to a website:

```
$browser = new-object -com “InternetExplorer.Application”
$browser.Navigate(“https://stackoverflow.com/”)
$browser.visible = $true
```

Comment: My server always in log off mode. In such case, it is not working.